Does $KerR_A = KerR_R$?
Assume A is a matrix, $L_A$ represents the linear map x→Ax, $R_A$ represents the linear map x→xA and R is the reduce row echelon form of A. By matrix multiplication rules we have $rkR_A = rowrank(A),rkL_A = colrank(A)$.
Since $Ax = 0$ iff $Rx = 0$, $KerL_A = KerL_R$. By rank-nuility theorem and the definition of RREF,
$colrank(A) = rkL_A = rkL_R = colrank(R) = rowrank(R) = rkR_R$.
Now we can see $rowrank(A)=colrank(A)$ iff $rkR_A = rkR_R$ iff $KerR_A$ = $KerR_R$. Is there any alternative way to prove $KerR_A$ = $KerR_R$ without using the argument $rowrank(A)=colrank(A)$, which results a alternative proof of this argument?

It is not true that $\ker R_A = \ker R_R$, only their dimensions are equal. As an example, consider
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&0\1&0}, \quad R = \pmatrix{1&0\0&0}.
$$

There are proofs that the row rank and column rank of a matrix are equal that make use of the reduced row-echelon form, though
